# malloc: nano zone abandoned due to inability to reserve vm space

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, runtime

I am getting following error when i upgrade the xcode version.

malloc: nano zone abandoned due to inability to reserve vm space.
Thread Performance Checker: Thread running at QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE waiting on a lower QoS thread running at QOS_CLASS_DEFAULT. Investigate ways to avoid priority inversions
PID: 7620, TID: 3294802

3   GPUToolsCore                        0x0000000108e55568 _ZN8GPUTools9Interpose15DYInitInterposeEPFP16DYGuestAppClientvEi + 404
......

objc[7620]: Swift class extensions and categories on Swift classes are not allowed to have +load methods

Is this something that you can resolve it?
Please could you help me?
Best regards.

I am trying to build source code in Xcode.
build is a success. but I get a runtime error.

Comment: Without knowing your code, it is difficult to judge wether this is an error in a system framework, a thirdparty framework, or your code. For example, regarding "Swift class extensions and categories on Swift classes are not allowed to have +load methods", do you define a `load` class method on a Swift class? Regarding the priority inversions, do you dispatch to queues with specified priorities (in particular do you use `userInteractive`) ? To debug, you should remove as much code as you can and see when the error goes away. Then add things to find the cause.

Comment: I am not getting any errors in compile and build. I am getting errors when the app is running on the device. I think it is a runtime error. after the ios app was installed on the device, it is occurring.

Comment: I understand. That was quite clear from your question, and that's what my comment was meant to address.

Comment: Just updated it ,do you have any idea?

Comment: This is the same information as before, and the suggestion is the same.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.